# is accessing number pickers in TimePicker possible?

Tags: java, android

It seems TimePicker is made of three inner NumberPickers. Is it possible to access them? it's needed to access and modify each of them.

```
public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
            implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        TimePicker dialog = new TimePicker(getActivity(), this, 22, 30,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return dialog;
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // Do something with the time chosen by the user
    }
}
```

In dialog, I've created a `TimePicker` to be shown, but I have to modify `TimePicker` minutes column(spinner) and add 15min intervals. I want to know if there is any way to access those NumberPickers alone.

**UPDATE**
i posted answer below, however it was one of the hardest modification in android built-in components for me, i finally found the answer and shared it here but idk why it got down-vote?

Comment: add your xml and java code

Comment: @MilanPansuriya updated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found a solution. i'm getting minute column here and setting a 15 minute interval there.

```
changeTimepicker(R.id.from_time_picker, 15);
```

method implementation:

```
try {
            Class<?> rClass = Class.forName("com.android.internal.R$id");
//            Field timePicker = rClass.getField(name);
            TimePicker mTimePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(id);

            Field m = rClass.getField("minute");

            NumberPicker mMinuteSpinner = (NumberPicker) mTimePicker.findViewById(m.getInt(null));
            mMinuteSpinner.setMinValue(0);
            mMinuteSpinner.setMaxValue((60 / increment) - 1);
            List<String> displayedValues = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 60; i += increment) {
                displayedValues.add(String.format("%02d", i));
            }

            mMinuteSpinner.setDisplayedValues(displayedValues.toArray(new String[0]));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```